# Serverless Security Groups are required to be in the same VPC

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-vpc

Currently I am facing an issue while trying to bind my serverless handlers to my vpc. My command to deploy is the following:

```
serverless deploy --aws-profile prod --stage prod --alias prod --verbose
```

I am using this [plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-vpc-plugin)

After getting the failed deploy I get the following error message:

```
Serverless: Operation failed!
Serverless: View the full error output: <error url>


 Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  
An error occurred: OnAddObligationFileLambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message: "Security Groups are required to be in the same VPC. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2a4e05b8-6b7b-470a-ab06-fe1ba22ec3c3, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 1417189a-154f-d638-6467-846b778c8850, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).
```

I wonder if this could be a problem with my security group configuration. Should I delete my lambda? Also the error message bugs me: "Security Groups are required to be in the same VPC", Security groups are required to be in the same vpc alongside with what? Same vpc as the lambda? Same vpc as the subnet? I hadn't understood that message. That is weird since these Subnets and security groups are already in the same vpc.

I keep getting the following failures in cloudformation during serverless deploy:

```
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::Lambda::Function - OnAddObligationFileLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::Lambda::Function - DownloadLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::Lambda::Function - FindAndStoreAllLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - UPDATE_FAILED - AWS::Lambda::Function - DownloadByFOIdLambdaFunction
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable6
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable4
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable1
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable3
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable6
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable2
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable3
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable1
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable5
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable4
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable5
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable2
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable6
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable2
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable1
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - AppRouteTable5
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - DBRouteTable4
CloudFormation - CREATE_FAILED - AWS::EC2::RouteTable - PublicRouteTable3
```

Following is my serverless.yml

```
service: functions-dte

provider:
  name: aws
  vpc:
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-*****************
      - subnet-*****************
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-***************
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: ${env:ENV}
  region: us-east-1
  timeout: 899
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: prod
    ENV: prod
    DB_URI: <mongo_uri>
    BUCKET_NC: ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.ncBucket}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - 's3:*'
      Resource: '*'

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-vpc-plugin
package:
  exclude:
    - config/.env.stg
    - config/.env.pro
  include:
    - config/.env.dev

functions:
  download:
    handler: src/handlers/app.download

  downloadByFOId:
    handler: src/handlers/app.downloadByFOId
  findAndStoreAll:
    handler: src/handlers/app.findAndStoreAll
    events:
      - http:
          path: findAndStoreAll
          method: post
  onAddObligationFile:
    handler: src/handlers/app.onAddObligationFile
    events:
      - http:
          path: onAddObligationFile
          method: post
      - s3:
          existing: ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.ncExisting}
          bucket: ${self:custom.${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}.ncBucket}
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules: 
            - suffix: .pdf
            - prefix: cloud/files/

custom:
  dev:
    ncBucket: gj-nextcloud-backend-dev
    ncExisting: false
  prod:
    ncBucket: gj-nextcloud-backend
    ncExisting: true
```

Comment: The security group is required to be in the same VPC as the subnet IDs you specify.

Comment: Thank you. This is the weirdest thing. they are already in the same vpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research we were able to connect our lambda to our vpc using serverless. The solution was: Stop using `serverless-vpc-plugin`.

It turns out that `serverless-vpc-plugin`, automatically creates a AWS VPC, which is not what we were looking for. We already had our VPC created using terraform.

From serverless-vpc-plugin [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-vpc-plugin)

> Automatically creates an AWS Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) using all
> available Availability Zones (AZ) in a region.

In other words, `serverless-vpc-plugin` doesn't make sense when the target vpc already exists